# Laravel 5.6.28: Auth Middleware redirects to Login (handle not called)

Tags: php, laravel

Auth middleware in laravel to authenticate users using my custom guard but everytime i call a route with that middleware I get the error that :

> Route [login] not defined.

Right now, i am just trying to make sure that the middleware is being called.This is what i have done so far:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{ 
    return "hi";
    if (Auth::guard('api')->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('hi/login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

the above is the handle method for authenticate.php. this is my code for guard

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'access_token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
 'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

The Routes:
This is the route group in which i have a sub-group that implements the auth 
middleware
     `Route::group(['prefix' => 'app'], function() use ($router) {  }`

This is the route i am testing the middleware on `Route::get('/subscribedcompanies','PromotionController@getFavoriteCompanies');`

One more Thing i'd like to add is i'm trying to authenticate based on access_token from database. i have changed the authenticate and credentials function in login controller as follows:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->header('authorization'));
}

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->header('authorization');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `php artisan make:auth` to scaffold the authentication pages needed?

Comment: show us your routes please!

Comment: please mention the version of laravel you are using.

Comment: @Iftikharuddin i dont really want the views that laravel generates . we are using laravel just for the api

Comment: @Iftikharuddin i have updated the question to show my routes

Comment: @RohitRai i have updated the title to show laravel version

Comment: can you show your login route

Comment: @hananhamza run `php artisan route:list` and paste the result please.

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya i want to authenticate using the middleware itself do i need a named login route for that?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin i cannot figure out how to format the result from php artisan route:list

Comment: Just copy and paste and did you tried Mayuri answer?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin i have updated the question . i am trying to authenticate based on access_token from databse . also if i create a login function and login route i  get a methodnotallowed exception because the login route is a post route

Answer (score 4):

just give name to your login route as `login`
`Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@index')->name('login');`

Comment: i have manual login and insta login both in my project.Not sure, how would that work .Moreover , can't i perform login in the middleware itself?